# Applying Chebyshev's inequality to a sequence of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent random variables. Assume that $E[X_k] = 0$ and $σ^2_k = E[X^2_k] < \infty$ for each $k$. I want to show that for all $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
P( \max_k |S_k| \ge \epsilon) ≤ \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \sum^n_{k=1} σ^2_k
$$
where $S_k = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_k$.

My thoughts: by Chebyshev, $P(|X_k| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \sigma_k^2$ for all $k$. Taking sum over $K$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_k| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \sum^n_{k=1} σ^2_k
$$
But I am having difficulty connecting $P(|X_k| \ge \epsilon)$ to $P( \max_k |S_k| \ge \epsilon)$. Since the $X_k$'s are independent, I know $
\sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_k| \ge \epsilon) = P(\max_k |X_k| \ge \epsilon)$. But I don't know how to proceed next. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Since the $X_k$'s are independent, I know $
\sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_k| \ge \epsilon) = P(\max_k |X_k| \ge \epsilon)$." --- What?  Is this a typo?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_k| \ge \epsilon)$ is the probability that at least one $|X_k| \ge \epsilon$, in which case the maximum of the $|X_k|$'s is $\ge \epsilon$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: No.  The probability that at least one $|X_k| \geq \epsilon$ is given by $P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n \{|X_k| \geq \epsilon\}\right)$, which is related to the sum by means of the inequality [by countable subadditivity] $$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n \{|X_k| \geq \epsilon\}\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n P(|X_k|\geq \epsilon).$$  You have equality if and only if the events $\{|X_k| \geq \epsilon\}$ are mutually exclusive, which for independent random variables means all but possibly one of the $n$ events has probability $0$, which is far too strong of a restriction to make it worth considering.

Answer (score 3):

This is an application of Doob's submartingale inequality. We consider $\mathscr{F}_k:=\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$. We first prove $S_k:=X_1+...+X_k$ is a martingale. $E[|S_k|^2]=V[S_k]=\sum_{\ell\leq k}\sigma^2_\ell<\infty$ so $S_k\in L^2\implies S_k\in L^1,\,\forall k$; then $E[S_k-S_{k-1}|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]=E[X_k|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]=E[X_k]=0$. Then we prove $|S_k|^2$ is a (nonnegative) submartingale:
$$E[|S_k|^2|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]\geq|E[S_k|\mathscr{F}_{k-1}]|^2=|S_{k-1}|^2 ,\,\forall k$$
Then we note $\max_{1\leq k \leq n}(|y_k|)^2=\max_{1\leq k \leq n}(|y_k|^2)$ so
$$P(\max_{1\leq k \leq n}|S_k|\geq a)= P(\max_{1\leq k \leq n}|S_k|^2\geq a^2)\leq a^{-2}E[|S_n|^2]=a^{-2}V[S_n]$$
and the result follows from the independence of the $X_k$'s.

Comment: Isnt ${|S_k|^2}$ is submartingale means $E(|S_k|^2  \ | \  |S_1|^2, \ .... \,|S_{k-1}|^2) \geq |S_{k-1}|^2$ ? But in ur derivation, u conditioned it on $X_1,....,X_{k-1}$ instead of $|S_1|^2, \ .... \,|S_{k-1}|^2$ and proved $E(|S_k|^2  \ | \  X_1, \ ... \ , X_{k-1}) \geq |S_{k-1}|^2$ 
 instead of $E(|S_k|^2  \ | \  |S_1|^2, \ .... \,|S_{k-1}|^2) \geq |S_{k-1}|^2$ . Can u explain a bit on the reasoning ? Nice answer !

Comment: Adding a reference to your answer. See Related inequalities in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality Here they directly prove its martingale and give the inequality. check it out.

Comment: @Balajisb thanks. This result is standard, but providing a proof may appear puzzling to those not yet acquainted to martingale theory. The filtration is $\mathscr{F}_n$ as defined above and that's what we use to decide if something is or not a martingale *with respect to it*. Note $S_n$ is a function of $X_1,...,X_n$.